# Creating a custom Wagtail OEmbedFinder

Tags: wagtail

I'm following [the documentation](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/advanced_topics/embeds.html#custom-embed-finder-classes) and also [this example](https://wagtail.io/blog/fixing-youtubes-oembed-implementation-custom-finder-class/) to create a custom OEmbed Finder in my Wagtail site. (Ultimately I want to modify the HTML output for YouTube videos to use the `youtube-nocookie.com` domain, rather than `youtube.com`.)

I have created this in `myapp.embeds.finders.oembed.py`:

```py
from wagtail.embeds.finders.oembed import OEmbedFinder

class YouTubeOEmbedFinder(OEmbedFinder):

    def find_embed(self, url, max_width=None):
        embed = super().find_embed(url, max_width)

        # Just to see that it's doing something:
        embed['html'] = '<p>Hello</p>'

        return embed
```

And added this in my settings:

```py
from wagtail.embeds.oembed_providers import youtube

WAGTAILEMBEDS_FINDERS = [
    {
        'class': 'myapp.embeds.finders.oembed.YouTubeOEmbedFinder',
        'providers': [youtube],
    },
    {
        # Handles all other oEmbed providers the default way
        'class': 'wagtail.embeds.finders.oembed',
    },
]
```

But nothing is different - the standard YouTube embed is in the published page. As far as I can tell, my `find_embed()` method is never called. I must have made some stupid mistake, but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debugging this was made a lot harder because I didn't realise one thing: Embeds, including their HTML, aren't always regenerated when you re-save, or publish, the Page they're used on. They're only regenerated if their URL changes. This is why my `find_embed()` method was never called; because I was just re-publishing the page, without changing the URL used in the embed.

Once I realised this, the solution for what I was trying to do was brief.

In my `settings.py`:

```py
from wagtail.embeds.oembed_providers import youtube

WAGTAILEMBEDS_FINDERS = [
    {
        'class': 'myapp.embeds.finders.oembed.YouTubeOEmbedFinder',
        'providers': [youtube],
    },
    {
        # Handles all other oEmbed providers the default way
        'class': 'wagtail.embeds.finders.oembed',
    },
]
```

And then in `myapp/embeds/finders/oembed.py`:

```py
from wagtail.embeds.finders.oembed import OEmbedFinder

class YouTubeOEmbedFinder(OEmbedFinder):
    """
    Ensures that all YouTube embeds use the youtube-nocookie.com domain
    instead of youtube.com.
    """

    def find_embed(self, url, max_width=None):
        embed = super().find_embed(url, max_width)

        embed['html'] = embed['html'].replace(
                                        'youtube.com/embed',
                                        'youtube-nocookie.com/embed')
        return embed
```

Then it was just a case of *changing the URLs for all my existing YouTube embeds* (e.g. by adding `?v=2` to the end of their URLs) and re-publishing the pages.

Comment: In case anyone finding this caching issue, use `manage.py purge_embeds` - https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/management_commands.html#purge-embeds